# Django registration : Error register a new user

Tags: django, registration

I'm using django-registration. I have included it into my project.
When I try to register a new user, I always have an error message.
I am using the development server (runserver).

I want to register the user and to send the activation e-mail.
This is the error :
[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
location : C:\Python27\lib\socket.py in create_connection, line 571

I think I have to do something on my settings.

Thank you

Comment: it looks like you are on a windows system which does not provide a SMTP server at all. So the process which consists to send an email failed with the connection to the SMTP server.

Comment: OK. SO how I can register a new user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a production environment or is it only a development?

If it is a development environment, you can use a file-based email backend: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#file-backend . If you use this backend your emails will be written to file. You will be able to read them with text editor.

If it is a production environment then you have to setup your SMTP server settings properly.

Comment: It's a development environment. I used EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'.                                      I can see now the activation link provided inside the mail. But when i put the activation link on the web browser, I have an error 404 page not found.

Comment: My activation link is http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/activate/0dafafe71274964a7ed0e6cbf93dad9c849=b9595/.                                                                 Whereas i have in my url conf : ^accounts/ ^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$ [name='registration_activate'] . Any idea please?

Comment: Your activation key does not match your regex `\w+`, because it has this symbol: `=` inside.

Comment: I solved the problem actually It's because I generate the email to send into a file thanks to email backends provided by django for development purpose. Inside this file, when there is a carriage return, it adds an = characters. And it's the case with the link to active the account.